# ffmpeg - avcodec_receive_frame returns -11, why and how to solve it?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm learning to use ffmpeg in my engine,

and I wanna decode the first frame of video stream and output it to an image file.

I tried and just can't figured out why it returns -11.

My code:(error in last 5 lines of code, line 70-74)

[Link to my code](https://gist.github.com/kalenclark/3434f4565fb9e41a1eb33b68bb8110c6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code (line 70 - 74):

```
res = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame);
if (res != 0)
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Let's see, what the documentation has to say about the related function ([avcodec_receive_frame](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga11e6542c4e66d3028668788a1a74217c)):

> **Returns**
>
> **0:** success, a frame was returned
>
> **AVERROR(EAGAIN):** output is not available in this state - user must try to send new input
>
> **AVERROR(EOF):** the decoder has been fully flushed, and there will be no more output frames
>
> **AVERROR(EINVAL):** codec not opened, or it is an encoder > 
> **other negative values:** legitimate decoding errors

You could just do the following:

```
switch (res) {
default: puts("unknown result"); break;
case 0: puts("success"); break;
case AVERROR(EAGAIN): puts("output is not available"); break;
//... you get the idea
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What error I got was actually AVERROR(EAGAIN), and after repeating decoding process from "av_read_frame", finally I made it. Thank you again~